# Error writing test case in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

Hi I am learning to write test cases with Rspec in ruby and am following this [link](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/ruby-for-newbies-testing-with-rspec/). So while testing the following case

```
 require 'spec_helper'

describe "Library object" do
before :all do
    lib_obj = [
        Book.new ("Javascript: The Good Parts", "Douglas Crockford", :development),
        Book.new ("Designing with Web Standards", "Jeffrey Zeldman", :design),
        Book.new ("Don't make me Think", "Steve krug", :usability),
        Book.new ("Javascript Patterns", "Stoyam Stefanov", :development),
        Book.new ("Responsive Web Design", "Ethan Marcotte", :design)
    ]       
    File.open "books.yml", "w" do |f|
        f.write YAML::dump lib_obj
    end
end

before :each do
    @lib = Library.new "books.yml"
end

describe "#new" do
    context "with no parameters" do
        it "has no books" do
            lib = Library.new
            lib.should have(0).books
        end
    end
    context "with a yaml file paramater" do
        it "has five books" do
            @lib.should have(5).books
        end
    end
end

it "returns all the books in a given category" do
    @lib.get_books_in_category(:development).length.should == 2
end

it "accepts new books" do
    @lib.add_book(Book.new("Designing for the Web", "Mark Boulton", :design))
    @lib.get_book("Designing for the Web").should be_an_instance_of Book
end

it "saves the library" do
    books = @lib.books.map { |book| book.title  }
    @lib.save
    lib2 = Library.new "books.yml"
    books2 = lib2.books.map { |book| book.title  }
    books.should eql books2
end
```

end

I am getting the following error:-

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
 Book.new ("Don't make me Think", "Steve krug", :usability),
```

This stands for all the entries in array lib_obj. 
I am using ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.6

Kindly help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra space between your method calls and argument lists.

```
Book.new (...)
```

...is not the same as:

```
Book.new(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

I see you are passing in string value's for a new Book class although you are not specifying the attribute you want to bind it to.

try:

```
new_book = Book.new(:name => "string", :cover_image => "string") etc.
```

also make sure your model validations and mass_assignment security are set correctly but your test will point you there soon.